# How to trigger email automatically without clicking send button when clicked on Mailto link

Tags: html, outlook

My title speaks what i need. Here is my scenario. My application will be sending html formatted emails to user with a Accept/Reject link. I would like to trigger email's automatically with a customized Subject to a mail id when the user clicks on Accept/Reject button.As Recipients of this mails are outlook users,i have to trigger send (ctrl+Enter) button of outlook. Is this possible with a mail-to link. 
Please don't suggest opening a page there by i can accomplish my task. That's not i want. Please help on this.

Comment: do you need your outlook mail will open for mailing when you click on the link ??

Comment: @Ron yes Ron. Actually the recipients will be having either outlook client or outlook web app. Mail will be received in any of these as html format. "mail-to" will be opening the outlook window. But what i need is , to send that reply email automatically when click on the mailto link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with a mailto link. Why not use the Outlook Object Model to create a new item and send it programmatically? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268749.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.To achieve this i need a outlook profile in the server where my app is deployed right?. And this sample will help to send the email to recipients My question is different. If the receiver(recipient) clicks on some link say Accept, then an email should be automatically create and send to specified address.

Comment: You will need to have Outlook installed wherever your user actually clicks the mailto url. If that is a script in web page, chances are you won't be able to do that unless your are using IE and your site is trusted so that the script is allowed to create COM objects.